# Question about rotation of spheres.

Tags: calculus

Hi my professor gave me a very weird question on a homework assignment, and I think it could be a typo.

Here's the question:
Find the volume of the solid (using calculus) obtained by rotating the region bounded by $x = 0$ and $x^2 + y^2 = 1$. Explain why your answer is correct.

Normally in order to rotate the shape he would need to give me an axis of rotation, but he has not, any ideas?

Comment: You're right: without specifying an axis of rotation, there are at least two viable possibilities (about each axis). None the less, the somewhat best choice is about the $y$-axis. In which case the answer below is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The equation $x^2+y^2=1$ represents a circle with center at the origin $(0, 0)$ & a radius of $1$ unit. The line $x=0$ represents the y-axis which equally divides the circle into two halves.

Thus the region bounded by $x=0$ & $x^2+y^2=1$ will be a semicircle which by rotating about the x-axis generates a semi-sphere whose volume is $$=\int_{x=0}^{x=1}\pi y^2dx$$  $$=\pi \int_{0}^{1} (1-x^2)dx$$ 
$$=\pi \left[x-\frac{x^3}{3}\right]_{0}^{1}$$ 
$$=\pi \left[1-\frac{1^3}{3}-0\right]$$ 
$$=\pi \left[\frac{2}{3}\right]$$ $$=\color{red}{\frac{2}{3}\pi}$$

Which is equal to the volume of the semi-sphere with unit radius  $$=\frac{2}{3}\pi(radius)^3$$ $$=\frac{2}{3}\pi(1)^3=\frac{2}{3}\pi$$

Both the above values are same hence, the answer is correct.